# Do you have to select a zombie before you roll a d6 for Shamble?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

One of the zombie cards, known as 'Shamble', has the following card text:

> Play this card to move a Zombie D6 spaces instead of its normal move.
>
> *"Look out!"*

Do you pick the zombie, then roll to see how far it moves?  Or do you roll a d6, and then pick a zombie to move that many spaces?

Answer (score 9):

According to the [game designer's response to the question on Board Game Geek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/1737165#1737165), you should pick the zombie before rolling.

> When playing Shamble you should choose the Zombie and then roll to see how far they get to move.